# Problem with writing code for projectile motion

Tags: c, projectile

I'm trying to write this code that calculates the final height and duration of flight for a projectile, while the user has to provide values for displacement, initial velocity, and launch angle. There aren't any compilation errors, but it's more of a logical error I'm dealing with. The final height value is completely wrong as well as the duration. Also after I enter the launch angle it doesn't instantly calculate the height and time. Instead I need to press the down key and then Enter for it to calculate. The compiler I call is [ gcc -Wall -Werror -ansi -o task2.out task2.c -lm] followed by the line [./task2.out]

```
#include <stdio.h> /* access to scanf, printf functions */
#include <math.h> /* access to trignometric functions */
#define g 9.8 /* acceleration due to gravity constant */
int main(void){
    double v, theta, t, x, h2;
    /* v = initial velocity
    theta = launch angle
    t = time
    x = horizontal displacement
    h2 = final height
    */

    printf("Enter range of projectile>");
    scanf("%lf", &x); /* assigned x as a long float */

    printf("Enter velocity>");
    scanf("%lf", &v); /* assigned v as a long float */

    printf("Enter angle>");
    scanf("%lf", &theta); /* assigned theta as a long float */

    scanf("%lf", &t); /* assigned t as a long float */
    t = x/v*cos(theta); /* formula for time */

    scanf("%lf", &h2); /* assigned h2 as a long float */
    h2 = (t*v*sin(theta)) - (0.5*g*t*t); /* formula for height */

    printf("Projectile final height was %.2lf metres./n", h2); 
    printf("Projectile duration was %.2lf seconds", t );

    return 0;       
}
```

Comment: Please initialise variables and check the return value of scanf() in all cases.

Comment: You get t from the user and then immediately overwrite it with the result of a calculation. Why ?

Comment: What do you see if you print all input values right after scanning them?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a debugger?

Comment: To fix the wrong values, try `t = x/(v*cos(theta));`, that might fix one of them, depending on what theta is. Which unit do you expect? Degrees(360)? Radians(2 Pi)?

Comment: Second value probably should be `h2 = (t*v*sin(theta)) - (0.25*g*t*t);` because the maximum height is reached after half the time. Assuming vacuum and flat environment.

Comment: I am not really entirely happy with people who ask a question and then leave. Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a few things (vacuum, flat environment, large earth radius, angle given via 2 Pi for a full cirlce, not 360), your calculations should be

```
t = x/(v*cos(theta));
```

because you need to divide by the horizontal part of velocity, not by velocity and then multiply by angles cosine.

```
h2 = (t*v*sin(theta)) - (0.25*g*t*t);
```

Because the maximum height is reached after hald the duration, not after the full duration.
That is why the integral of gravity-related acceleration (0.5 * g * t * t) only needs to be subtracted half.

The problem with the need to enter more things than just the numbers is covered already by the older answer by john, see there.

Answer (score 1):

`It doesn't instantly calculate`. That's because you are trying to read an extra number

```
scanf("%lf", &t); /* assigned t as a long float */
```

Remove that line. The formula on the next line calculates the time.

Same error for the height,

```
scanf("%lf", &h2); /* assigned h2 as a long float */
```

Remove that line as well.

Comment: Twice, actually. But how does this explain wrong values?

Comment: You mean "without asking for it such as `printf("Enter time>");`"

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes, I missed that. I've no idea about the wrong values, but might as well fix one error at a time.

Comment: That is whay multi-questions are discouraged.